# Border-radius: 50% not producing perfect circles in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Usually `border-radius: 50%` works fine for most applications, and Chrome produces what looks like a circle. But in this instance, I am trying to continually rotate a circle quickly, and this is where this problems shows itself.

Is this a bug with Chrome's border-radius? Or is this something with the transform?

Can anyone suggest a work around?

Edit: removed outdated example link

Comment: Most of the effect I'm seeing is visual – simply due to the color differences. However, the edge still wobbles slightly when modified to uniform colors. This _might_ be due to rounding errors in which case using 51% should solve your problems, but it might also simply be a rendering issue.

Comment: Modifying the border-radius didn't change it for me, and removing the rotation and looking closely you can see the deformation

Comment: I'm thinking it's lack of resolution in chrome's rendering engine because of the way circles are faked by computers. IE They decided this was "good enough". See http://i.imgur.com/pzOd5dM.gif

Comment: It's also wobbly in IE, firefox works fine.

Comment: @FordFiler I think you are right. One solution I came up with was to create another larger circle with a small border of the background color to overlap and hide that wobble. Though, I was hoping for a less  hackey solution.

Comment: Will it be spinning in the final product? If so that's unfortunate... if it's critical maybe consider just using a gif rather than css?

Comment: @FordFiler I think you're right about using a GIF instead here, even if that animation works OK, it consumes CPU too much, it's totally unacceptable and it's of course just something for fun.

Comment: @FordFiler Yeah, it will be spinning in the final product, although much more slowly so the wobble won't be as noticeable. I may just go with a GIF for this.

Comment: I like that effect. :D

Comment: The demo can not reach now.

Answer (score 3):

It's caused by the roundings in the way the "radius" is calculated. Since the size is an even number the border is "in-between" two pixels... long history, at the end:

**Workarround:** Set your divs circles size an "odd" number of pixels.

```
$ring-medium-outer: 437px;
$ring-medium-inner: 381px;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Didn't make sense in my head at first, but now I get it.

Comment: I can't get this workaround to work. It produces the same result regardless of even or odd number of pixels.

Answer (score 1):

We have a solution an effective solution as of Dec 2022: Compatible with all major browsers...

If the `border-radius` value is half of the width value for that specific element; in CSS, we get a full circle for that element, provided that a `height` property with an equal value of the `width` or an `aspect-ratio` property is specified for that element. Example with an `img` element below…

```
img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

OR

```
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 75px;
}
```

Extra Note: To scale the `width` and `height` dynamically for dynamic CSS’ units, `aspect-ratio` property to the rescue.