# Firefox not rendering correctly with: border-radius,box-shadow and border

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

In the example bellow:

http://jsfiddle.net/Du8f6/3/

Im setting inner shadow to the container and 10px border with border-radius set to 50%.
And the result is weired thin white border outside the container border.

The thin white border is visible in:

```
mozilla firefox
ie 11
```

and its not visible in:

```
opera
safari
chrome
```

any suggestions for fixing this are welcome.

Comment: Your code needs to be in the question (unless your code really consists of the names of browsers). Please don't circumvent the quality filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the way the border is rendered: painted over the div. It's another "half pixel" issue and the border color mixs with the div background color... Take a look to [Border-radius: 50% not producing perfect circles in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070899/border-radius-50-not-producing-perfect-circles-in-chrome) or [IE11 draws small line between positioned elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380720/ie11-draws-small-line-between-positioned-elements/) . Those are not the same issue, but have the same origin.

Probably your easier workaround is to skip out the border width of the div and set up a "fake" border using the background of a new wrapper div:

In your html:

```
<div class="fakeborder"><div class="sub">Hm</div></div>
```

and in your css:

```
.sub {
    ...
    border: 0px solid black;
    ... 
}

.fakeborder{
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;     /*The fake border width*/
    background:black; /*The fake border color*/
}
```

Comment: This was the solution I needed! I was struggling for a line time with a thin partial pixel while trying to make a feather-edged circle in Firefox. See my pain here: https://jsfiddle.net/dustinfreeman/ag4kcr5y/86/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
Even if I set

```
box-shadow:0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

to the element just because I didn't want a box-shadow for that element and I thought I could override the property like this.

That was working in webkit browsers, but FF was still rendering a thin shadow.

A better solution and the best practice to override a css property to its default, it is obviously set it to its default (dumb!)

```
box-shadow: none
```