# Transform rotate not working properly in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

The following code renders a perfect rotating circle in safari, **but not in chrome**.

```
<style>
.circle{
    height:1000px;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
from{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
to{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}

.rotating {
    -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
}
</style>

<div class="circle rotating">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4ban9cs/

It does not renders perfectly, the problem is visible when rotating a big circle, it's like a wiggling circle on chrome.

thank you for help.

Comment: so what is the problem, not rotating ? not perfect circle ?

Comment: Your fiddle works for me in Chrome.

Comment: @AndréDion For me it renders a "wiggling" circle (chrome 39 wind 7)

Comment: [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4ban9cs/5/) with a few properties changed/added to more easily see the animation.

Comment: i think you want this ....http://jsfiddle.net/p4ban9cs/8/

Comment: yes the div is rotating but it does "wiggle wiggle" like @web-tiki said. when we rotate a circle it is supposed to seems not moving.

Comment: @user00000341, the bug is not visible on a little circle. look at the same code with 1000x1000px http://jsfiddle.net/p4ban9cs/9/ (on chrome)

Comment: There is an uresolved duplicate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070899/border-radius-50-not-producing-perfect-circles-in-chrome The suggestion seems to be to use an image..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli the main need it to produce this effect http://jsfiddle.net/L2r6tjq8/1/, the inset shadows does not seems affected by the bug. I need the outer shadow to hide a bottom content layer overflow.

Comment: @ensixte the inset shadow is affect when applied to the circle. It's noticeable in the original example if the size of the shadow gets greater than 100px.

Comment: @Anima-t3d look http://jsfiddle.net/p4ban9cs/11/ the inset shadow does not wiggle like the circle, it appears to be a perfect circle.

Comment: @Anima-t3d same code but with an outset shadow http://jsfiddle.net/p4ban9cs/12/ it follows the edge of the circle ...

Comment: @ensixte if it is for overflowed content of the same element why not remove the outer shadow and set `overflow:hidden` to it ? http://jsfiddle.net/L2r6tjq8/2/

Answer (score 1):

Adding an outer element as a wrapper and apply same styling to it, to mask the inner circle rotation as seen in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4ban9cs/13/)

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="circle rotating">Test</div>
</div>

.overlay{
    height:1000px;
    width:1000px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 10px #000 ;
    background:black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help =), but it does not seems to work, just change the color of the overlay box-shadow to see the result http://jsfiddle.net/p4ban9cs/18/ with the same colour it seems correct but that doesn't solve the problem, i tried a lot of hiding tricks but no one works (no visually perfect result), that is why i gone to the base of the problem, why chrome renders like that ?!

thank you again for your help.

Comment: @ensixte It was not meant to be fix the base of the problem. It was meant to visually look good ;-) The problem seems to be an issue with how chrome calculates `border-radius` I tried verifying this by rotating without `border-radius` but it's hard to confirm it rotating around the correct pivot point, making a perfect circle with the corners...